# How to make a template private to a custom tag

Tags: jsrender

I see that there is a syntax to have a helper that is private to a template but is there a syntax for the opposite?  I have a tag that uses a specific template and that template (logically speaking) is only used by the tag.

```
$.templates({
  link_template: "<a href='{{:link}}' class='{{:klass}}'>{{:text}}</a>"
});

$.views.tags({
link_to: function (link, klass, text) {
    return $.render.link_template({link: link, klass: klass, text: text});
}
});
```

I considered having the template be just a string but then it would be compiled on each call.  I'd like to get the benefit of having the template be compiled (essentially, what I have right now -- I just want to somehow hide the template inside the tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some variants:

```
$.views.tags({
    link_to1: {
        template: "<a href='{{:link}}' class='{{:klass}}'>{{:text}}</a>"
    },
    link_to2: {
        render: function (link, klass, text) {
            return this.template.render({link: link, klass: klass, text: text});
        },
        template: "<a href='{{:link}}' class='{{:klass}}'>{{:text}}</a>"
    },
    link_to3: {
        render: function (link, klass, text) {
            return this.myTemplate.render({link: link, klass: klass, text: text});
        },
        myTemplate: $.templates("<a href='{{:link}}' class='{{:klass}}'>{{:text}}</a>")
    }
});
```

In each case the template will only get compiled once, and will be private.

The first case and the second are similar, but the second lets you control the rendering programatically. Compilation is done when the tag is compiled.

The third lets you have several private templates...